# How to find this limit of $\tan(n\pi)/(n-1)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to find this limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\tan(n\pi)}{n-1}$$
but I couldn't. Here's what I tried

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\tan(n\pi)}{n-1} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{\cos(n\pi)}\frac{1}{n-1} \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{n\pi}\frac{n\pi}{\cos(n\pi)(n-1)} \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{n\pi}\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{n\pi}{\cos(n\pi)(n-1)} \\
&=0
\end{align}$$
But the answer is $\pi$, this is very counter intuitive. Could someone make this result clear?

Thanks

Comment: $\tan(n\pi) = \tan((n-1)\pi)$.

Comment: Your left limit goes to 0 but your right limit diverges to $\infty$. So you can't split the limits up like this.

Comment: How about using L'Hopital's Rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Setting  $n-1=m\iff n=m+1$

$$F=\lim_{n\to1}\frac{\tan n\pi}{n-1}=\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\tan (m+1)\pi}m$$

As $\tan(\pi+y)=\tan y,F$ Reduces to

$$\pi\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\sin m\pi}{m\pi}\cdot\frac1{\lim_{m\to0}\cos m\pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\tan (\pi x)$ then
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\tan(\pi x)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(1)=\pi(1+\tan^2(\pi))=\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Well it's simple,

$tan(\pi*n) \underset{n \to 1} \sim \pi*(n-1) $

So $ \forall n \in \mathbb{R}, \frac{\pi(n-1)}{(n-1)}=\pi $

So the answer is : $ \pi $

Shadock

Answer (score 1):

using L'Hopitalrule

$sec^2(n\pi).\pi/1$ 
put n=1 then $\pi(sec^2(\pi))=\pi$