# Finding $ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\tan \pi x}{1-x} $ without L’Hôpital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\tan \pi x}{1-x} 
$$
WITHOUT using L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/870995/42969

Comment: Can you use taylor expansion ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is also an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: Known limits involving  ratios of $\tan$ (Note that $\tan(\pi x)=-\tan(\pi(1-x)$? Geometric arguments and squeeze theorem? Taylor series?  What context do you have for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=1+y.$ If $0<|y|<1/2$ then $$\frac {\tan \pi x}{1-x}=\frac {1}{1-\tan \pi y}\cdot\frac {\tan \pi y}{\pi y}\cdot \pi$$ and $y\to 0$ as $x\to 1.$